# How to modify the zookeeper port, while storm running in local mode?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

While running apache storm in local mode, zookeeper will initialized by storm with port "2000". i want to change the this port. how can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change storm.zookeeper.port:xxxx (XXXX is port-number you want to change).

Comment: Hi Dilip, I have tried with keeping configuration as 5000 but storm initializing zookeeper with 2000 port, for your reference see below log 
14216 [main] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer - Created server with tickTime 2000 minSessionTimeout 4000 maxSessionTimeout 40000 datadir C:\Users\hemanth.v\AppData\Local\Temp\75136b5d-7a48-4271-8870-763c5d464c0d\version-2 snapdir C:\Users\hemanth.v\AppData\Local\Temp\75136b5d-7a48-4271-8870-763c5d464c0d\version-2
14257 [main] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000

Comment: when you change the port,it should bind from the changed port only ! can you show your configuration file once.

Comment: Hi Dilip, this are zookeeper configurations in storm.yaml storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "10.113.56.63"
 storm.zookeeper.port: 5000

Comment: okay i think you did not changed the port id in zoo-keeper ! did you changed the port id in zoo.cfg  file ?

Comment: Hi Dilip, In local cluster storm has to initialize the it own zookeeper right. then where can we update zookeeper related configurations in storm.

Comment: Did you installed storm single node yourself ? or used any other pre installed vms.i mean Hdp(sandbox),cloudera or any other distributions gives you pre installed setup of hadoop and storm.You can find the installation of only storm and zookeeper path in blog link http://bigdatadays.blogspot.in/

Comment: Hi Dilip, I have checked in the storm code. storm always initializes the zookeeper with port 2000, if we specify the zookeeper server and zookeeper port then it will connects to that. check LocalCluster class for more info

Answer (score 0):

you can set it through "storm.zookeeper.port" property.